# Is it possible to call a switch case statement from a main project in a class which this class is already included to main project?

Tags: c++, class, visual-c++, switch-statement

I defined a **MfC** project in **visual C++** environment and I wrote switch case statements for this project. Then I included a class consist of a `OnPaint()` handle message with possibility to brush something.

After that I called this `OnPaint()` function in a Case of the main project's Switch cases by using an object. Now I'm going to put a condition for `onPaint()` function that if this Case happened use a brush with this class otherwise other color.
Therefore, I want to know if there is a possibility to call a switch case statement from a main project in one of its classes?

```
void Myclass::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting
    //@TG
    //#3073
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here
    // Do not call CStatic::OnPaint() for painting messages
    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);
    switch(StatusFunction)
    {
      case 1:
        dc.FillSolidRect(&rect, RGB(255, 0, 0));
    }
     case 2:
    {
        dc.FillSolidRect(&rect, RGB(0, 255, 0));

    }
}
```

update:

I think the problem does not solve with Invalidate a control. This class is defined to paint a Picture control because of this I defined a variable for this picture control  like `CPictureCtr m_Pc;` which is located upon a dialog box(In Visual C++) then a class drived to paint just this control(Named CPictureCtr). In drived class a OnPaint() handle message defined. In one of the cases of switch case statements I called OnPaint() as follows:

```
m_Pc.EnableWindow(TRUE);
m_Pc.Invalidate();
```

However the problem is that when in one case these lines of code enable, OnPaint() function in drived class use this line :`dc.FillSolidRect(&rect, RGB(255, 0, 0));`. I'm just trying in the same **OnPaint()** funnction put a condition to read `dc.FillSolidRect(&rect, RGB(0, 255, 0))` which changes color of the same picture control when another case happens.

Comment: Very unclear what you're asking ... you can't "call a switch statement".  Perhaps posting some relevant bits of code might clarify what you want to know.

Comment: Why do you want a switch inside your if statements?

Comment: I included`OnPaint()` Function

Comment: @drescherjm Since in those **Cases**, this **OnPaint()** function is called to paint some controllers.

Comment: @drescherjm plz check out updated part

Comment: The class that contains the OnPaint function needs to have a member variable like your "StatusFunction" variable. Set that variable to control which color is painted.

Comment: @ScottMcP-MVP In my case, StatusFunction is a Structure and is consist of different variables such as 1, 2 .... , I already assigned a variable to the Picture Control and changed type of that variable to drived class in main header, like this `CPictureCtr m_Pc;`.Then, called that `variable.EnableWindow(TRUE);` and variable.Invalidate(); in **Cases** of interest in main cpp file. I would like to ask you where should I declare a new variable and where should call it, in this class or in main cpp?

Answer (score 1):

Generically, you can extract your `switch` statement into a method, and call that method. Or in your particular case, you probably want to a setter for your `case1` variable, and then invalidate your view with `CWnd::Invalidate()`. This will call the `OnPaint` method.

Comment: Yes extract a switch statement in the same class is possible however now I am trying to call this switch statement from a class which is subclass of this class, it has error and requires a argument for **switch** (that in this case the argument for switch is a defined function from the main class).  Question updated.

Comment: ***I am trying to call this switch statement from a class which is subclass of this class*** Can't you just Invalidate to force the paint?

Comment: @Braian just call `this->Invalidate();` from your subclass, like I said. It will result in `OnPaint` being called.

Comment: @Braian You need to set a boolean variable on your control, which will form the basis of your switch inside `OnPaint`.